# Newb: WPF custom graphic control - where to start

Tags: graphics, wpf-controls

Apologies if there is a thread for this already, I couldn't find one that I could get my teeth into.

Anyway, I'm new to WPF and want to create a custom control that will be a sort of graphic control. The graphic will always consist of a circle, containing a matrix of several squares (from several hundred to several thousand actually) The squares need to respond to mouse click and mouse over events (and ideally be possible to navigate/select via keyboard.) Each square will represent an object I've coded.

In the past I've used a grid control to display the coloured squares (with VCL in CBuilder) but I would like to make a graphical version. (Actually, another question I'd like to ask is, is there a WPF grid control where I can set the colours of individual cells?)

The question is, where to start? Do I start with a canvas and draw on it? Do I derive from an existing object? I'm just a little lacking on ideas on implementation so any pointers or advice you can offer will be greatly received.

BBz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off I would suggest getting a decent handle on [WPF](http://windowsclient.net/learn/) and how it approaches the problem set. It is vastly different from previous .NET Desktop technologies such as WinForms. Once you have a decent understanding in regards to the separation of logic from UI and how WPF approaches the problem then you can dive in and begin making the right decisions based upon what you encounter.

The problem you mention can be solved in multiple ways. In regards to your question about making use of a `Grid`, that could be done as that is a layout type. It is vastly superior to the `Canvas` in terms of arranging your visual structure. The defined rows/columns are nothing more then containers which can hold varying UI objects. Therefore pushing a `Rectangle` into the `Grid` and coloring as desired would give you the effect you are looking for. This `Rectangle` could then become a custom control which would allow you to define varying properties on, as well as specific triggers for mouse overs, etc...

At a higher level you will want to encapsulate this logic as a `UserControl` which will also hold your custom control. Perhaps the `UserControl` contains the `Grid` which will make use of your custom control.

Hopefully this gives you some ideas around how to get started, however getting a better understanding of WPF will help you immensely in achieving your goal.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The grid sounds ok, although I wonder what the memory requirements might be for several thousand rectangles in a grid. Also, is it easy to dynamically adjust the row & col count of said grid?

Comment: Yep adjusting the row/col count is easy, here is a post about the Grid control in WPF...http://blogonwpfwcf.blogspot.com/2009/02/grid-in-wpf.html I'm not sure what the memory requirements would be as it depends on the rectangle and what it does or does not hold, however I don't think they would be to bad. The reason I say this is that I have seen Silverlight Grids containing hundreds of car images and you narrow down the results, was fairly performant and via the browser.